# Unity Dialog System That Shows Each Sentence On Key Press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialog

I've been using one of Brackey's tutorials on creating an RPG like dialog system in Unity but changing it so that instead of pressing a button, you should press space to show the dialogue. I've got two scripts, one to trigger the dialogue and the other to display the dialogue. A problem I'm having is only the first line of the dialogue appears. When adding press keys to advance the sentences, only the last line of dialog would show up. What do I need to do to make each sentence appear on each key press.

First script triggers dialog through collision and pressing space key.

```
public Dialogue dialogue;

public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    //Only trigger dialog when player collides with dialog area and presses space.
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Player") {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
                FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager> ().StartDialogue (dialogue);

            }
        }
    }
```

Then display dialogue. Also I know there is the danger of pressing space to call StartDialog over and over instead of advancing the sentences but even when I changed the keys it didn't work.

```
    public Text nameText;
    public Text dialogueText;
    private Queue<string> sentences;

    void Start () {
        sentences = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void StartDialogue (Dialogue dialogue)
    {
        nameText.text = dialogue.name;
        sentences.Clear();

        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences) {

                sentences.Enqueue (sentence);
                Debug.Log (sentence);
        }
                DisplayNextSentence ();
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence ()
    {
        if (sentences.Count == 0) {
            //end dialog
            return;
        }
            string sentence = sentences.Dequeue ();
            StopAllCoroutines ();
            dialogueText.text = sentence;
            //Make text appear letter by letter.
            StartCoroutine (TypeSentence (sentence));
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting `sentence = sentences.Dequeue()` will give you the string only for the message exiting the queue right?

Comment: The `DisplayNextSentence` method is only called once, is this normal?

Comment: I think you should check that the `DisplayNextSentence `is called, also you should check that it's not adding more dialogs to the queue when you press the button.